# Simulating parent class, reverse polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism, asp.net-4.0

I have 2 already defined classes, we'll call them `DogActivityType` and `HorseActivityType`.
They have the same fields, same methods, but they write to 2 different tables in the database, and of course, are named differently.

I have a function with all the business rules already working for one class, and the other class uses the same business rules.

Restrictions:

1. I have to use these 2 classes since they are used throughout other parts of the project
2. I can't create one class and add another column (field) to distinguish between both types of classes.
3. I can't edit the source for these 2 classes.

.
Here is my simplified version of the code:

```
public doAllCalculations(){
  // retrieve collection
  foreach (DogActivityType activity in allActivities){
    // a lot of code here

    // more code... 

    createMoreOf(activity);  // this is overloaded since it needs to know which DB to write to
  }
}

// using overload for same function name
private createMoreOf(DogActivityType doggyActivity){
    /// do some specific when it is a dog
}

private createMoreOf(HorseActivityType horse){
    /// do some specific when it is a horse
}
```

Now, the problem is: `doAllCalculations()` is very extensive and complicated and may change during the course of development.  I don't want to have 2 different functions (`doAllCalculationsDOG()` and `doAllCalculationsHORSE()` ) in order to do the same analysis, just because I need one for the `Dog` and another for the `Horse` class.  One day someone in the project may forget to update both functions or any other bad scenario...

So, I want to use the same function for both classes.  So if I edit a rule in the big calculation function, I will know it works for both classes.
I'm thinking I'll end up with something like this:

```
public class AnimalActityType {

}

public doAllCalculations(){
  // retrieve collection
  foreach (AnimalActivityType activity in allActivities){
    // a lot of code here
    // more code... 
    createMoreOf(activity); 
  }
}
```

`AnimalActityType` will simulate an abstract parent, I'll call it reverse polymorphism...
But how do DogActityType and HorseActityType know about this parent? Can I force the parent?
Is it possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use decorator pattern, but in very unusual way.

```
    class Decorator
{
    private object instance;

    public Decprator(object instance)
    {
         this.instance = instance;
    }

    public <type> SomeCommonProp
    {
      get{
        if(instance is DogActivityType)
        {
          return (instance as DogActivityType).SomeValueOrPropertyOrCall;
        }
        else
        {
          return (instance as HorseActivityType).SomeValueOrPropertyOrCall; 
        }
      }
    }
}


class MyCalculations
{
  private Decorator instance;

  public MyCalculations(Decorator inst)
  {
      instance = inst;
  }

  public <type> SomeCalculationMethod()
  {
    // here you will use instance.SomeCommonProp for your calculations
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly!!  I did some modifications and had to create a GET for all the similar fields. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 4):

> I can't edit the source for these 2 classes.

Assuming this means you can't create a base class or even an interface to me this says that even if you come up with a solution it's going to be nothing but a messy hack job. I'd sooner try to find a way around this self imposed restriction than come up with some perverted form of polymorphism.

Comment: The restrictions are not self-imposed. I know it will be a hack job, that's what I want to do :)  Maybe from a messy hack job idea, I can take the time to make it pretty.

Comment: Perhaps not by you, but by your manager, his manager or his. Somewhere along the line someone is making technical decisions that has no business doing so because if they did this restraint wouldn't be here.